# ajax image upload with Java rest service

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, rest

I am trying to upload an image from the client using an AJAX call to a Rest Service.  What I have is uploading the image.  The size of the image matches exactly, and in windows explorer, the image preview looks like my image.  But, when I double click the .png file, the image is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Client: (event.target.files[0] is the file selected from a file dialog box)

```
let file = event.target.files[0];

  $.ajax({
                url: URL.BUILDER_URL + '/megaUpload',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType : "multipart/form-data",
                data: file,
                processData: false
            });
```

Server:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("megaUpload")
    public Response upload(InputStream fileInputStream) throws Exception {
        String uploadFileLocation = "C:\\temp\\bla.png";

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadFileLocation));
        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your path on upload method is not good. Use /megaUpload

Comment: this article can help you: https://javatutorial.net/java-file-upload-rest-service

Comment: Sonor that article knocked it out of the park!  Thank you!!!